# Android saved activity state in onResume?

Tags: android

How do I record the start time of the stopWatch using system.currentTimeMillis? when your `activity` `onResume()` or `onStart()` is called, how do I update the watch to show the time that elapsed from the time it's saved? Thanks. What I have tried so far without `onResume()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
    setContentView(R.layout.stopwatch);
    getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, R.drawable.clock32);

    // initializes controls
    initControls();

    // sets format for chronometer
    chronometer.setText( "00:00:00" );


}


private void initControls(){

    // initializes buttons & chronometer
    pause = ( Button ) findViewById ( R.id.btStopWatchPause );
    stop = ( Button ) findViewById ( R.id.btStopWatchStop );
    start = ( Button) findViewById ( R.id.btStopWatchStart );
    reset = ( Button ) findViewById ( R.id.btStopWatchReset );
    chronometer = ( Chronometer ) findViewById ( R.id.chronometer );

    // sets listeners for buttons and chronometer
    pause.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);
    start.setOnClickListener(this);
    reset.setOnClickListener(this);
    chronometer.setOnChronometerTickListener(this);


}


public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch( v.getId() )
    {
    case R.id.btStopWatchStart:
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + timeWhenStopped);
        chronometer.start();
        break;
    case R.id.btStopWatchStop:
        chronometer.stop();
        break;
    case R.id.btStopWatchReset:
        chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        break;
    case R.id.btStopWatchPause:
        timeWhenStopped = chronometer.getBase() - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        chronometer.stop();
        break;

    } // end of switch statement

}

public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer c) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    CharSequence text = c.getText();
    if ( text.length()  == 5 ) {
        c.setText( "00:" + text );
    } else if ( text.length() == 7 ) {
        c.setText( "0" + text );
    }



} // end of onChronometerTick method
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    TimeForActivity.StartTimer(AccountingTab.this);

    public class TimeForActivity implements Constants{
    public static void StartTimer(Context context, TextView aTvTime, Button aBtUserStatus, ProgressDialog aProgressDialog, String sessionID) {

        mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);

        activity = context;
        tvTime = aTvTime;       
        btUserStatus = aBtUserStatus;

        tvTime.setText("");
        btUserStatus.setText(statusItems[userStatus - 1]);


        btUserStatus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showStatusDialog();
            }
        });
        progressDialog = aProgressDialog;       

        reStartTimer();
    }
    private static void reStartTimer() {


    if (pageConfig.getUserStatusTime() != null && StatusService.methodType != StatusService.GO_OUT) {

            if (mStartTime == null)
                mStartTime = pageConfig.getUserStatusTime() * 60 * 1000 - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
            //CommonHelper.showToastMsg(activity, Long.toString(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()));
            //tvUserStatus.setText(Long.toString(SystemClock.uptimeMillis()) + " mStarTime: " + mStartTime);
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
            mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
        }
    }

private static Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            try {
                final long start = mStartTime;          
                long millis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + start;
                long seconds = (long) (millis / 1000);
                long hours =  seconds / 3600;
                seconds -= hours * 3600;
                long minutes = seconds / 60;
                seconds     = seconds % 60;


                tvTime.setText(CommonHelper.getTwoDigitTime(hours) +  ":" + CommonHelper.getTwoDigitTime(minutes)); 
                        //+ ":" + CommonHelper.getTwoDigitTime(seconds));
                //java.lang.System.out.println(tvTime.getText().toString());
                if (userStatus == StatusService.GO_OUT){
                   tvTime.setText("");
                   stopTimer();
                }
                if (StatusService.methodType != StatusService.GO_OUT)
                    mHandler.postAtTime(this, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 60*1000);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

        }
    };
    }
```